# Rails: Why do my fixtures have the same ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've started writing a test:

```
class PostPresenterTest < ActionView::TestCase
  let(:presenter) { PostPresenter.new(post, view) }
  let(:post) { Post.first }

  it 'should something something...' do
    byebug
  end
end
```

I have the `post.yml` fixture file:

```
  one:
    title: Title One
    content: First content.

  two:
    title: Title Two
    content: Second content.
```

When I drop into byebug, I notice `Post.count == 2` but the individual posts have the same id:

```
  Post.first.id == 298486374
  Post.last.id == 298486374
```

Is this expected? I need to ensure that each post has its own unique ID. What is the rails standard for adding ids to fixtures? Should I add ids manually or is there a specific step that I should take to ensure the posts have distinct ids?

Comment: According [to the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html) omitting the ID should lead to the ids being autogenerated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that I assumed that `Post.first` and `Post.last` returned different posts. They actually returned the same post. The ids *are* different.

```
(byebug) Post.all
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 298486374, title: "Title Two", content: "Second content.", created_at: "2017-06-01 06:44:50", updated_at: "2017-06-01 06:44:50">, #<Post id: 980190962, title: "Title One", content: "First content.", created_at: "2017-06-01 06:44:50", updated_at: "2017-06-01 06:44:50">]>
```

I tried `Post.order("created_at").first` and `Post.order("created_at").first` but those too returned the same post. I realised that this was because both posts had the same created dates. Adding the dates manually fixed this issue. `#last` and `#first` now return different posts.